# Count Names In Multiple Rows & Group Them By Location In Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, count, sum, flatten, google-query-language

I've been attempting to use Query to group up and count information in the Attempts column below, but I'm running into walls.

[image]

When using a Query formula like below, I seem to be on the right track in getting all the information I want to see, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR({A3:A6,SPLIT($D3:$D6, ":;, ()", 1)}, "")), "select *"))
```

My desired result is to essentially count all the people in Column D and associate them with the location. Ideally, if I could get it so that the formula performed in the way of "If A12:A14 Matched A3:A6, it would group all the results together of D3:D6 and then count them, displaying the results in D12:D14". I appreciate your assistance and time!

[image]

Comment: You input seems incomplete. Can you explain, how desired is 6 for first row?

Comment: 6 from the first row comes from the 6 names listed in Column D that correspond with "Track" in Column A. Frank, Jane, Frank, Rebecca, Jane, and Jane were all attempts made. Does that make sense?

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as [**plain text table**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to the question. Adding such "markdown tables" greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A12:A14, 
 QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(SPLIT(D3:D6, ",")="",,A3:A6)), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1"), 2, )))
```

[image]